# Smart way to column-wise create "categorical version" of continuous data for a matrix in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I am trying to create a "percentile" version of a matrix A by
First, calculate percentile cut-offs for each column
Then, for each column in matrix A, create a vector of equal length, the new vector should only have values 1 to 10, with 1 for a value falling in the first decile, and so on
The final output should be a matrix B that has the same dimension as matrix A, and B has only values 1 through 10.
A sample matrix A is

```
set.seed(1)
matrix(rnorm(5 * 5000, 1, 0.5), ncol = 5, nrow = 5000)
```

I have been using a for loop for each column but feel there must be a smarter way to do this.. Any tips & tricks are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need 5000 rows for this example? Surely a handful would do.

Comment: The matrix of my headache is more like 100K+ rows, so I put 5000 in the original post to show a flavor of it. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
m = matrix(rnorm(5 * 10, 1, 0.5), ncol = 5, nrow = 10)
apply(X = m, MARGIN = 2, function(a)
    findInterval(x = a, left.open = FALSE, rightmost.closed = TRUE,
                           vec = quantile(x = a, probs = 0:10/10)))
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    3   10   10   10    4
 [2,]    5    5    9    4    3
 [3,]    1    2    6    7    8
 [4,]   10    1    1    6    7
 [5,]    6    9    8    1    2
 [6,]    2    3    5    2    1
 [7,]    7    4    4    3    6
 [8,]    9    8    2    5    9
 [9,]    8    7    3    9    5
[10,]    4    6    7    8   10
```

Comment: Looks good on a quick eyeball. cut() might be another option too.

Comment: Thank you both! Yes I came across & figured out cut() in the nick of time.. now the spaghetti codes became much nicer and can output the "cutoff" matrix and the matrix B.
@d.b: Thank you for the solution with apply()! I was wondering how to use it to solve this but could not figure out the function.